# Unable to write to a java file *properly*

Tags: java, file-io

I have to read a text file and based on some logic, make some changes to the file. So I am reading the file line by line by using

```
 while ( (temp_string = inputstream.readLine()) != null )
 {
    /*after employing some other logic*/
    outputstream.write(temp_string);
    outputstream.flush();
}
```

Where temp_string is a String, and the declaration for inputstream is :

```
BufferedReader inputstream  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathtosilentfile));
```

and the declaration of `outputstream` is :

```
BufferedWriter outputstream = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathtooutputfile));
```

But when i write to the text file (new one) there is a lot of garbage, that shows on notepad++ as NULL. Also, the written data looks ok in notepad or wordpad. So is this some kind of an encoding error ? I dont get it ! Whats going wronng ?

Comment: If you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, that would really help. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet actually I just came back home from work so I cant do that anymore. However, I assure you that I am doing nothing more than I have expressed here in that snippet.

Comment: actually I wanted to paste the data from notepad++, but those guys at work have firewalled imgur

Comment: If you run just this snippet you will note that it works as expected (unless you were expecting newlines to magically appear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would really have helped if you'd told us what `output_stream` is - but it *should* be a `Writer` of some description - probably an `OutputStreamWriter` wrapped around a `FileStream`, specifying the appropriate encoding (which is up to you, I guess).

If it looks okay in Notepad / Wordpad, but broken in Notepad++, then it probably *is* an encoding issue, but you ought to decide which encoding to use. UTF-8 is often a good choice (compact for ASCII, covers the whole of Unicode, widely supported) but it depends on what needs to read the file.

Comment: I am sorry I did not mention the declaration of outputstream, but yes, it indeed is a BufferedWriter wrapped around a FileWriter. I had not given any thought to encoding till now, but I will explore the respective java API thoroughly tomorrow and see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For one, you're reading lines and not writing any newlines. The `temp_string` doesn't contain any newlines/linefeeds. Though that doesn't seem to be the only problem you're having.

Comment: actually I missed putting the `outputstream.newLine()` here in the snippet, but its there in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Loads of `NULL` at the beginning means that you started writing into the middle of a file instead of the beginning. Notepad/Wordpad simplistically just ignore this but your files are going to be far bigger than you want and may cause problems when read into other files.

However, as we don't know what `outputstream` is or what's been done to it before you started writing, we can't help you.

Comment: yes sir, you are right, I am indeed trying to write to the end of the file each time. What is the right way to do so, beacause this IS what I need to do. I need to read each line, see if it matches some properties, if yes, then alter the line and write it, andif no, then simply add the line as it is to the new copy of the file.